# CR/LF in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

How can I detect CR and/or LF in Emacs? Since I want to i-search CRLF, I prefer simpler way (e.g. no or less regex). Only relevant web page I've found is [this](http://codeshal.tumblr.com/post/407432473/inserting-a-carriage-return-in-emacs-search-replace) but `c-q c-j` didn't work.

Thanks!

Environment) GNU Emacs 22.3.1 (i386-apple-darwin9.8.0, Carbon Version 1.6.0), but I also want to know how to do this on linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>C-s</kbd> to start i-search, then <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> should work.  Control-Q quotes the next character as a literal, and control-J is a literal linefeed ("LF" or newline).

If you're dealing with a file that has carriage returns (CRLF line endings), Emacs will automatically use a DOS buffer file coding system and convert them to just linefeeds when loaded, and reconvert them to CRLFs when saved.  If you really want carriage returns in your buffer, run <kbd>M-x revert-buffer-with-coding-system unix</kbd>.  Then carriage returns will be displayed in your buffer as `^M`.  In this case, you can search for them with <kbd>C-s</kbd> to start i-search, then <kbd>C-q C-j C-q C-m</kbd>.